# Lmfit nan values

Tags: python

I'm trying to fit a distribution. The model that I've used is:

```
def quasiParabolic(x, n, sigma):
    fact1 = (1/(2*np.pi*sigma))
    fact2 =((n+1)/n)
    fact = fact1*fact2
    pot1 = 1-(1/n)
    pot2 = ((x**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))
    pot = (pot1*pot2)**n
    return fact*pot
```

The code used is:

```
#DATA NORMALIZATION
areaData = simps(integr, colPosmm)
y_ = integr/areaData
area2 = simps(y_, colPosmm)
print 'Integral normalized data B2',area2
print ''

#LMFIT
gmodel = Model(quasiParabolic)
params = Parameters()
params.add('n', value=2, min=0)
params.add('sigma', value=1, min=0)

# FIT
result3Q = gmodel.fit(y_, x=colPosmm, params=params)

#SAVE PARAMETERS
for param in result3L.params.values():
    if param.name == 'n':
         nval = param.value
    if param.name == 'sigma':
         sigmaval = param.value

#PARAMETERS REPORT
print '\033[4mQUASIPARAMETRIC MODEL B1 \033[0m'
print(result3Q.fit_report())
print ''

#PLOT FIT
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(colPosmm, result3Q.best_fit, 'c-', label="Lmfit Quasiparabolic" )
plt.legend()

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(colPosmm, result3Q.best_fit, 'c-', label="Lmfit Quasiparabolic" )
plt.legend()
```

When I run the script it returns me this error:

```
ValueError: The input contains nan values
```

I've tried to check the `nan` values, and they are in the variable `pot` (defined in the definition of the function).

I also printed y_ and colPosmm to be sure that there wasn't nan values and so it is.

I tried also to substitute the exponential `n` in pot formula with 2 (just to do a test), and in this case the script works.

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lmfit and other fitting methods from `scipy` sensibly (IMHO) cannot recover well when it encounters a value of NaN in the residual array (either model or data to be fit to that model).   This is pretty sensible, really:  If there is a NaN, any value derived from that value will be NaN, so the fit will think chi-square is NaN and will not know whether the sum-of-squares of the residual has been improved.

For your data, I would guess that you are running into a situation at

```
pot = (pot1*pot2)**n
```

in which `pot1*pot2` is negative (for some values).

Since you are allowing `n` to be fitted, it will be a double precision real, not just an integer.   And, of course,

```
 x ** n
```

is `NaN` for `x < 0` and non-integer `n`.

So, I think you'll either want to guard against `pot1*pot2` being negative or fix `n` to some integer value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to print the values of `pot` and as you said they are negative values. So because of I can't fix `n` to an integer value (I want Lmfit to evaluate the optimal value for `n`) I tried to do `abs(pot1*pot2)` and doing so I haven't any error. Now if I plot the distribution I have something like a Gaussian, but the tails of the distribution tend to go upward at the ends and I can't understand why. I tried to plot the same function in Wolfram Alpha and I obteined a perfect Gaussian distribution. Any idea on how to check this "error"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why this function would give a perfect Gaussian distribution.  It's very hard to answer follow-up questions in comments.   It seems like this really is a new question that would probably need a more thorough explanation (including data and results).